# golang adding spaces after strings by default?

Tags: string, go, println

I'm learning Go and one annoyance I have with it is when i use fmt.Println it adds a space after every argument passed (even variables). Is there a way to remove this space so it only adds a space if I add one in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Printf" function with format string instead.

```
fmt.Printf("string %s, integer %d, anything %v\n", "hello", 1, struct {}{})
```

Comment: (`Printf` would be fine, with a `\n` added to the format string)

Comment: Yes, as hobbs stated, the fmt.Printf() did the trick! fmt.Println() just printed the specifiers and not their values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("With","Space")
    fmt.Printf("%s%s\n","No","Space")
}
```

[example](http://play.golang.org/p/H-otSYDEN4)

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that works like println, where you don't have to put %v markers, then fmt.Print does the job.

it doesn't add spaces between arguments, and also doesn't add a newline.

for example:

`fmt.Print("a","b","c","\n")`

prints:
abc